# if statement executing when it is either false or true

Tags: java

so a bit of context:
I'm creating a program to manage products (candles) and I need to check if the name of the candles perfume exists before updating the data. 
So after some research I wrote this :

```
try {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();

        //Get a perfumeCode from a perfumeName
        sql = "SELECT Code_Parfum FROM T_Parfum WHERE Nom_Parfum = \"" + tbxPerfumeName.getText() + "\";";
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        System.out.println(!rs.next()); // = true if doesn't exists and = false if it does exist
        if (!rs.next()) {
            System.out.println("Ce produit n'exist pas !!"); //prints an error to help me see if this works
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {

    }
```

In short: It gets the name of the perfume I entered (in a textField) and returns me a ResultSet.
With that resultset I can check if the code of the perfume exists with rs.next()

The problem is: for the print... It works fine !! 
When it does not exist, I get **true** (because of "**!**") and when it does exist I get **false**!
But when it comes to the if, it does not work anymore. Everytime I try, the print inside the if gets executed. Everytime. Even if **!rs.next()** is true or false. Here is what I get as an output:

```
Connection to SQLite has been established.
false
Ce produit n'exist pas !!
DataBase Closed
Connection to SQLite has been established.
true
Ce produit n'exist pas !!
DataBase Closed
```

as you can see: I get **false** the first time (I entered a name that existed) and **true** the other (name does not exist) but the **if** printed the String in both cases. Despite having the same condition than the print before.

Am I missing something ? Why doesn't I get the "same" result (if true in print, then true in if, and vice-versa) ? 
Any help appreciated and thanks !

Comment: Every time you call `rs.next()` it advances the result set.

Comment: Not related but, why not using [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead?

Comment: Start by reading the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next--).

Comment: @shmosel Will do next time ! I'm a beginner and found online the .next() so I just used it. I will learn from this dumb mistake. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each call to `rs.next()` moves the cursor to the next result. So:

```
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

Now the cursor is at position -1 (ie before the first result set).

```
    System.out.println(!rs.next()); // = true if doesn't exists and = false if it does exist
```

Now the cursor is at position 0, at the first result; this result exists so the call returns `true`.

```
    if (!rs.next()) {
```

Now the cursor is at position 1; because only one result was returned, that position does not exist and the call returns `false`.

Answer (score 5):

You have to call `rs.next()` only once, because next time you call it, it checks for the next row, Also take a look at the [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) class, you shouldn't concatenate directly string to the query because this could lead to [SQLInjection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: thanks ! It's my bad I didn't check the documentation ... I searched on google to see how to check if data exists and found that .next() was used a lot, so I used it !
As for the PreparedStatement, I know it exists and I even use it. I just wanted fast writing to try the .next().
Thanks again !